# Changing bitmap color/hue efficiently in Android

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, hsv, hsl

I am using the following method to change the hue of a bitmap:

```
public Bitmap changeHue( Bitmap source, double hue ) {

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap( screenWidth, screenHeight, source.getConfig() );

    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    for( int x = 0; x < source.getWidth(); x++ ) {
        for( int y = 0; y < source.getHeight(); y++ ) {
            int c = source.getPixel( x, y );
            Color.colorToHSV( c, hsv );
            hsv[0] = (float) ((hsv[0] + 360 * hue) % 360);
            c = (Color.HSVToColor( hsv ) & 0x00ffffff) | (c & 0xff000000);
            result.setPixel( x, y, c );
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It works perfectly and maintains the luminance of the bitmap. However this method is very slow when changing the hue of a bitmap size 800*480 or higher. How can I optimize it without losing too much image quality?

Comment: You will probably have to use OpenGL to exploit the GPU.

Comment: As addendum to @Gene's answer: for newer devices (>= HoneyComb) you can use RenderScript to significantly speed up image manipulation. There's pretty decent [blog post on developer.android.com](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2012/01/levels-in-renderscript.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your Bitmap in an `ImageView` there is a very simple way:

```
ImageView circle = new ImageView(this);
circle.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap);
circle.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
```